# Returning byte array from server is different when received by the client

Tags: c#, rest, serialization, arrays, asp.net-web-api

I have a REST API trying to call (acquire) a byte array from my web api.
This is my client code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(URL);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/Binary"));
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri + route + "?" + COMPANY_REF + "=" + ApplicationObject.CompanyRef);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var result = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result
```

This is my server API:

```
[HttpGet]
public byte[] Get(Guid companyRef)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Services.Group,Models.Group>();
    var test = Mapper.Map<List<Models.Group>>(groupRepository.Get(companyRef));
    var t = Compression.Serialize(test);
    return t;
}


public static byte[] Serialize(this Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, obj);
        var compressed = Compression.Zip(memoryStream.ToArray());

        return compressed;
    }
}
```

The byte array returned by the server is:

[image]

the byte array received by the client is:

[image]

As you can see it is the wrong size and values.

I am assuming this is down to the media header which is currently set at:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/Binary"));
```

Using Fiddler it seems to think it is expecting Json. So I had changed it to 
    'Application/json'

That did nto work.

I also used base64Binary and that did not work either.

What else can I try?

ADDITIONAL:
Result when I type api direct into browser:

```
<base64Binary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
H4sIAAAAAAAEAKWS32vUQBDHN3u5TXJRUSr1B4pBX49g/4CDlhb64K9Dq304jjWXTK/rbXePbCKc4N8qCIIgCILvOnO92KDNkxP2m2SYz8zszjKPMfYLjd5kVzjK7jHMxrasMj1M3kDplDWjnfQxPcNkv9ZVXcLIQF2VFDGuZ1rlT2B1ZBdgRqbW2qd0H1+tXAVn6b7VGvIKk7j0EAyUKk+fKle93ZlM/hRKn9kCNAaUtl4Ok/9tYDrtYQdCKmzA9aVTHyCU788z+YzdvrzuZEq7D8OI4BBXhCugH+ZtPP725SiBkU/SJxEkAck6DeWJBiQxSp/iOvKsK6+/XsKJ/zw7g/gAXF6qJR1gz/Pizake1qqgov5PnF7bSRW4zLiccZlzWXAJXJ5wOefylEvF5TsuF+zCwiDgG2N/mbiKEh/ZIlu55NiWC3GNvOfFPNoo7cT7gR1QF//g11F6e1qLGy1MNNj3LmwLZfDaZM6puYFC3GzRQUN/66K3KeLFEoy41eLChvvaxd2hWY/BFMrMxd0WGjXoly70HqF7M5wmdnu/hQ4a9HMX+oAiDqwBkbS4uOE+dXEPKcLg9RCPaEbFxR2JfwNB64eo1AMAAA==
</base64Binary>
```

MORE INFO:

If change this:

```
 var result = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
    byte[] resultFromServer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("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");
    byte[] actualBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(resultFromServer));
```

To this:

```
var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
byte[] resultFromServer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result);
byte[] actualBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(resultFromServer));
```

I get the error:

**The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.**

This is the value of result

"H4sIAAAAAAAEAKWS32vUQBDHN3u5TXJRUSr1B4pBX49g/4CDlhb64K9Dq304jjWXTK/rbXePb
CKc4N8qCIIgCILvOnO92KDNkxP2m2SYz8zszjKPMfYLjd5kVzjK7jHMxrasMj1M3kDplDWjnfQ
xPcNkv9ZVXcLIQF2VFDGuZ1rlT2B1ZBdgRqbW2qd0H1+tXAVn6b7VGvIKk7j0EAyUKk
+fKle93ZlM/hRKn9kCNAaUtl4Ok/9tYDrtYQdCKmzA9aVTHyCU788z
+YzdvrzuZEq7D8OI4BBXhCugH
+ZtPP725SiBkU/SJxEkAck6DeWJBiQxSp/iOvKsK6+/XsKJ/zw7g/gAXF6qJR1gz/Pizake1qq
gov5PnF7bSRW4zLiccZlzWXAJXJ5wOefylEvF5TsuF
+zCwiDgG2N/mbiKEh/ZIlu55NiWC3GNvOfFPNoo7cT7gR1QF//g11F6e1qLGy1MNNj3LmwLZfD
aZM6puYFC3GzRQUN/66K3KeLFEoy41eLChvvaxd2hWY/BFMrMxd0WGjXoly70HqF7M5wmdnu/h
Q4a9HMX+oAiDqwBkbS4uOE+dXEPKcLg9RCPaEbFxR2JfwNB64eo1AMAAA=="

From Debug.Write:

"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"

To make this finally work I had to do this:

```
byte[] actualBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(result2.Replace("\"",""));
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered converting resulting byte array into uft-8 string or just reading content as a string? Maybe there us some info hidden in there

Comment: @RX_DID_RX Hi, thanks for taking pity on me.  I have edited my question to show what happens if I type the api directly into a browser. I will of course convert  to utf-8 as you suggested and report back. thanks

Comment: @RX_DID_RX All I got from the utf-8 is the same as the additional info :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are getting the response as string, just decode that Base64 string.

```cs
var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
byte[] actualBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(result);
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting a weirder result. I shall edit my question to explain

Comment: But I can succcessfully get the actualBytes and can see that it is the same as your byte[] sent from the web server. After you edit your post, I copied the base64 content and assigned it to result and still success.

Comment: Ok, now you are already getting the result as string, then you can only decode it.

Comment: That was what I meant by weird.  Copy and paste that string and it works but reading directly from the result variable it does not. There must be some conversion in the act of copying and pasting.  Been Googling this for some time now. Why me?

Comment: Then the result variable must have some kind of extra characters inside it. Can you please dump it with Debug.Write?

Comment: values are definitely not equal as used String.IsEqual test on it.  But what the diff is and how to correct it I am still looking :)

Comment: the difference is that the quotation speech marks are included in the start and end of what is returned from there server for some reason??

Comment: I am going to award you the accepted answer to this because you got me on the right track so thanks

Comment: Thank you. What an interesting problem! quotation marks.. First for me too!

Answer (score 4):

After some research i found that asp net core team don't want to fix this issue (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7926), to fix your problem you have to return "FileStreamResult".

Change your controller with this

```
[HttpGet]
public FileStreamResult Get(Guid companyRef)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Services.Group, Models.Group>();
    var test = Mapper.Map<List<Models.Group>>(groupRepository.Get(companyRef));
    var t = Compression.Serialize(test);
    return File(new MemoryStream(t), "application/octet-stream");
}
```